# How to save and pass a variable in Matlab

Tags: matlab, sum, digits

I can find / identify all digits in a number using a recursive function.

My issue is trying to sum the number through each recursion.

I had to initialize `sum = 0` at the top of my function statement, and when I return through recursion,  I'm always resetting sum back to zero. I do not know how to save a variable without first initalizing it.

Code is below;

```
function output= digit_sum(input)
sum=0
  
if input < 10
    output = input

else
     
    y=rem(input,10);
    sum=sum+y
    z=floor(input/10);
    digit_sum(z)
    
end
output=sum
end
```

Comment: Don't call a mean `mean`, a max `max` or indeed a sum `sum`. That's a built-in function and overwriting it is prone to lead to hard to debug errors. Call it `my_sum`, or a more descriptive name not shadowing a built-in function.

Comment: You may need to give `digit_sum` a second argument, the cumulative sum so far.